# How to make an IntentService wait until BroadcastReceiver has finished executing?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi, intentservice

I've got an *IntentService* which should perform some tasks **after** WiFi has been turned on.

I'm using a *BroadcastReceiver* on `WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` to listen for WiFi changes.

**The problem:**

When I turn on WiFi via `wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true)` the *BroadcastReceiver* only receives the states `WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED` and `WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING`. Then the *IntentService* is destroyed before the actual `WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED` state can be received.

If I put `Thread.sleep(2000)` at the end of `onHandleIntent()` it works, but there must be a better solution?

**Questions:**

1. Why is the state `WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED` broadcasted at all when I'm calling `wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true)`?
2. How can I make the `onHandleIntent()` method wait until the state `WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED` has been retrieved?

Code:

```
public class BackupService extends IntentService {

    private BroadcastReceiver mWifiStateChangedReceiver;

    public BackupService() {
        super("BackupService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        mWifiStateChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int wifiState = intent.getIntExtra(
                        WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,
                        WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);
                if (wifiState == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) {
                    // PERFORM TASK...
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(mWifiStateChangedReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mWifiStateChangedReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(mWifiStateChangedReceiver);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make the onHandleIntent() method wait until the state WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED has been retrieved?

Ideally, you don't, as WiFi may not be available, and so you may never receive such a broadcast.

Instead:

- Move your `BroadcastReceiver` to be one registered in the manifest, initially disabled
- If the `IntentService` determines that it needs to wait for WiFi, have it enable the existing `BroadcastReceiver` via `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`, then return out of `onHandleIntent()`
- The `BroadcastReceiver` would use `startService()` to send a command to be processed by your `IntentService` once WiFi is ready, at which point it can then disable itself via `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`

Comment: I think that's not right. The broadcast `WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED`  is always sent when turning on WiFi, no matter if a WiFi network is available or not. I think what you mean is `WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION` which indicates whether it's connected or not.

Comment: Apart from that, thanks for your answer! However, your solution implies that my `IntentService` is destroyed once and then re-started. I cannot do that since I'm executing crucial commands in the `onDestroy()` method which determine the further application flow. Any chance to wait for WiFi being enabled without destroying the `IntentService`?

Comment: @Jens: First, that code should not reside in `onDestroy()` in all likelihood. The primary point of an `IntentService` is to do work in the background thread (e.g., `onHandleIntent()`). `onDestroy()`, like all lifecycle methods, is called on the main application thread. If you move it to `onHandleIntent()`, you can also simply only execute that code when needed (i.e., only in the case where you did the work based on WiFi availability).

Comment: Thank you! That last comment made me refactor my basic `IntentService` structure and now everything is working as it should.